# Add-In to Switch Selection [ArcMap 10.4]

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, add-in

I'm creating a suite of add-in tools on a tool bar, and using this tool as a test. How I want it to work is thus:

- I have a buffer which has already been cut up by a line feature class
- I select the portions of the cut-up buffer that I want to keep (will usually be 
  1-2)
- I then press my add-in button, which switches my selection to all other parts of 
  the buffer (I will then add in 'delete all' functionality).

I have gone through the process and created the add-in project, toolbar, button etc., and loaded it into ArcMap through the customize menu. The button appears as intended, no 'Missing' issues. However, when I attempt to use it as described above, I get an egg-timer for a brief moment, and then nothing appears to happen. There is no change in the selection after I press the button compared to before.

My code:

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins


class InverseSelection(object):
    """Implementation for RAFTv2_addin.invbtn (Button)"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False

    def onClick(self):
        buffcut = "U:/ArcGIS/Default.gdb/buffcut"
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
        df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(buffcut, "NEW_SELECTION", "INVERT")

    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

I have also tried "SWITCH-SELECTION", but that didn't work either.

Comment: You need to read the help file and understand the syntax of the select by attribute tool. You are using the wrong parameter, look for the word switch.

Comment: Are you talking about "SWITCH_SELECTION"? If so I tried that with no success, as stated. Will try again though.

Comment: But if switch selection and then invert...you are back to square 1.

Comment: The invert_where_clause parameter doesn't exist for 10.4; it's only in Pro. But you don't need it, anyway. As Hornbydd implied, the selection line should read `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(buffcut, "SWITCH_SELECTION")`.

Comment: Still no luck. I select a part of my buffer, press my add-in button and get an egg-timer for a second, but then my selection remains the same and doesn't switch.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I got it working

> arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("buffcut", "SWITCH_SELECTION")

I needed to wrap buffcut with "". I thought setting it earlier on was the correct method but apparently not!